# How can I iterate through a map and add its elements to an ArrayList using recursion?

Tags: java

I have a TreeMap called mapDependecies :

`TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapDep`

example of my map :

`[a=[b, c], c=[f,e], b=[], f=[x,y]`

So each key (example a) depends from it's values (b,c).
I want to put the key with it's dependencies, and their dependencies in an Array.

I want the result to be as follows :

`Array = [[a,b,c,f,x,y,e], [c,f,x,y,e], b[], [f,x,y]]`

How can I use recursion to get the result wanted?

Comment: You don't need java8 here, just use a for loop and do it.

Comment: I don't need recursion?

Comment: I'd say yes recursion, because you don't know the length of dependencies

Comment: Think of an algorithm that can be used here. I would suggest you to look at topological sort. Iterative approach sounds more appropriate to me. If I were you, I wouldn't use java8 here.

Comment: Hum, just find out you don't want to follow the dependencies, just one level in fact

Comment: Why isn't it `Array = [[a,b,c,f,x,y,e], [c,f,x,y,e], b[], [f,x,y]]` ?  Does the order matter?   Note that this is the problem with just giving an example rather than explaining clearly what you want.  Examples are never a proper specification.  (And they could contain mistakes.)

Comment: You are absolutely right, your list is the right example I will change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need recursion, to get the dependencies again and again, so call the method again and again :

```
static List<String> getDeps(TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapDep, String key) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(key));
    if (mapDep.containsKey(key)) {
        for (String val : mapDep.get(key)) {
            res.addAll(getDeps(mapDep, val)); // call again with new key from V
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Using

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String key : mapDep.keySet()) {
    result.add(getDeps(mapDep, key));
}
System.out.println(result); //[[a, b, c, f, x, y, e], [b], [c, f, x, y, e], [f, x, y]]
```

Comment: I have changed my question, actually I do want to follow my dependencies. it's just the example I wrote in the first time was wrong. The result expected : Array = [[a,b,c,f,x,y,e], [c,f,x,y,e], b[], [f,x,y]]